# What can you say about groups if every homomorphism is trivial?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose we have two groups $G,H$, and the premise is that **every** homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is trivial.

This certainly can happen when either of $G,H$ is trivial, but is it possible that neither of $G,H$ are trivial?

Comment: What about $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Yes. Take $C_p$ and $C_q$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Comment: More generally, if $G$ and $H$ have finite coprime exponents, there will not be any nontrivial homomorphisms $G \to H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remember that there are $(m,n)$ number of homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$, see [Find the number of homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825829/find-the-number-of-homomorphisms-between-mathbbz-m-and-mathbbz-n?noredirect=1&lq=1). Hence if $n$ amd $m$ are coprime, there is only one homomorphism. So it is not necessary for both groups to be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Try $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 2):

There are other examples. If $G=\mathbb{Q}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}$ are the additive group of rational numbers and the additive group of integers respectively, then every homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

By the First homomorphism theorem, this also happens if $G$ is simple and $|H|< |G|$. For example, $A_5\to S_4$.

Comment: Oh right, very nice!